# R - effects function on mlogit - error "no individual index"

Tags: r, effects, mlogit

I have successfully run a mlogit like this:

```
Base3<-mlogit(choice ~  return + risk + measure + pureplay + bestinclass + fee, Data,
               rpar=c(return = 'n', risk = 'n', measure = 'n', pureplay = 'n'),
               R = 100, halton = NA, panel = TRUE)
```

Now i would like to see the marginal effects of the attributes and tried this:

```
effects(Base3, covariate = "return", type = "ar")
```

I have tried different attributes under "covariate" and also to take it out completely but i always get the error message:

*Error in mlogit(formula = choice ~ return + risk + measure + pureplay +  :
no individual index*

I would really appreciate some help on why this happens.
Thank you!

Comment: Seems your error appears in the `mlogit()` rather than in the `effects()`.

Comment: But i can run the mlogit without a problem and do a summary of it with valid results..

Comment: I can't because you didn't [share data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and error states "Error in **mlogit**".